# MS Access queries

Tags: ms-access, sqlcommand

I must understand few things about MS access queries, and this is why I'm coming here.
First of all - my task list is written in Latvian (hate that), this is why I can't understand simple things.
Here is my one of tasks: "Make four simple queries, where shows specific, not-specific, number intervals, less than and greater than."
Probably I didn't translated my task correctly, but I can't understand, what does means specific and not-specific query.
This is too simple for me, and this is why I don't get it.

And also I wanted to ask, if there is any SQL commands, which does the same thing like in PHP function substr(). As I tried to use SQL commands, which I use daily writing MySQL queries, does not work in MS Access.

I hope, that some one could help me about this :) Thanks!

/Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references that may help:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

As for substr, you can use Mid, Left, Right, InStr and InstrRev.